# Why does my class's p.length() return None?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was trying the following code to dynamically add a method to a class, in Python:

```
class SomeClass():

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.name)

p = SomeClass("Bob", 22)

def f(v):
    print len(v)

SomeClass.length = f

print p.length()
```

Since the `len()` function depends on the `__len__` method of the object which is used in the parameter, I expected the output to be:

```
3
```

However, I'm getting the output as:

```
3
None
```

Why is there a `None` in the output?

Comment: Because you printed the return value of `p.length()`. The `length` method has no `return` statement so the default `None` is returned.

Comment: Nowhere does `__len__` here print `None`.

Comment: Because `f(v)` already does the printing instead of returning the value (which is not a good idea, but anyway). So **you only want to call `p.length()`**, not `print p.length()`, which will print the return value, which is None.

Comment: In general, don't define methods which print things. Return the thing to the caller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from `f`. So by default `None` will be returned. When you do `print p.length()`, `p.length` actually prints the length and returns `None` and that is what is getting printed.

Instead, just return the length from `f`.

```
def f(v):
    return len(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `f` *prints* the length, and then *returns* nothing, i.e. `None`, and you *print* whatever `f` returns with `print p.length()`. If you want to output only `3`, then *either* change `f` to

```
def f(v):
    return len(v)  # return instead of print
```

*or* change the call to `f` to

```
p.length()  # without the print
```

Answer (score 1):

`f` prints the length of name, which produces 3. Then you are printing the return value of `f` but `f` returns `None`, which produces your `None` in the output.